# Python extension wants to relaunch the all instances of the integrated terminal each time I close and reopen VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda, miniconda

During the last few days each time I reopen VS Code there is a yellow caution symbol on each instance of the integrated terminal saying:

> "The following extensions want to relaunch the terminal to contribute to its environment: Python."

This never used to happen, nor does it happen on my laptop which has its settings sync with VS Code on my desktop.

I have tried reinstalling the Python extension but this has not resolved this issue. I am using Miniconda as my Python interpreter if that is of any relevance.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could advise me on resolving this issue!

Comment: Try [completely uninstalling vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall) and starting again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following setting

```json
    "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false,
```

More related settings here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue but of course now if I close vscode and reopen my terminal history is not restored. Are you aware of what could be causing this issue since it does not persist between my synced vscode accounts on my other devices?

Comment: I have the same issue, appreciate if someone can provide assistance

Comment: This may be related to your python extension, what version of vscode and python extension are you using? Try rolling back a version or using a pre-release version of the python extension.

Comment: Apologies for the break in replying. The issue now seems to have resolved itself, though it is unclear why.

Comment: glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)